# Green bathtub chip repair

Tags: repair, bathtub, green, chip

We have a 1960s sea foam green tub with a small chip in it. Is there a product that I can colour match this colour?

Comment: Does the chip go all the way through to the metal below? If not, a clear repair would allow the green to be seen through it and would be mostly invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Exact color-matching is hard, YMMV.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Porc-a-Fix-Touch-up-Repair-Glaze-Kohler-Seafoam-Green-KK-41/514315463